# SharePoint Deployment from Visual Studio 2010 Location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, deployment

So I have a web application in visual studio. I can right click on the project and click Deploy which will send the files live to the SharePoint server.

I accidentally reverted one of the pages to an older version in Visual Studio and was wondering if it's possible to get the version running live on the SharePoint server as that is the latest version.

I cannot currently deploy as this will then run and old version of the page I accidental reverted.

Where would the files be stored and how could I find them? visual Studio is running on the SharePoint server.

Thank you very much!

Comment: As I understand you have a Solution for your SharePoint (2010?). In this solution there is a Page (aspx?) file which is deployed to the SP but reverted in you VS. And you would deploy your currently reverted version? Or do you want to know where VS does deploy your Pages? What is your solution structure, pagetype, features, modules etc.?

Comment: The version of the page in VS is an older version (reverted) than the one live in SharePoint. I would like to retrieve the version on share point back into VS. Are the files saved in: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\"name of Web Application + port"

Comment: Have you tried to open the page in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: I do not have SharePoint designer installed. Was wondering if there was another way. Can you also access the aspx.cs page in sharepoint designer?

Comment: Ah ok. you thought of the aspx.cs this file is not accessible by SPD.

Comment: I need both files. The aspx and the aspx.cs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42033/discussion-between-safinn-and-martin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio does compile your `*.aspx.cs` files to the `*.dll` file of your Solution/Project.
If you want to get the code of your old `*.aspx.cs` file you can use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to decompile your `*.dll` (actually deployed to your SharePoint) and find the *old* code by namespace.

Comment: Got my aspx.cs page using ILSpy. Thank you.